# mediasoup - miss match between PayloadTypes

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, rtp, sdp, opus

I'm trying to use mediasoup to forward RTP streams with `room.createRtpStreamer`

my problem is that the payload type (for OPUS) I get from `producer.rtpParameters.codecs[i].payloadType` is 111,
while the one I get on the actual RTP packets is 100 (seen on Wireshark)

I tried to set `preferredPayloadType` in my server's config, but it seems to make no difference.

Note:
if I hardcode 100 as the Payload Type for the OPUS stream I can view/hear the stream using FFPlay

I'm using Chrome 55 (latest) and mediasoup 2.0.5 (latest)

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The `Producer` has the RTP parameters decided by the client (browser), so the PT of OPUS is 111 (the default value generated by Chrome).

But, once in mediasoup server, the `Consumers` associated to that `Producer` use the RTP parameters given during the room creation. So, if the codecs given to `room = new server.Room(codecs)` [1] have a `preferredPayloadType` field, that will be used within the `Consumers` (otherwise it will be randomly chosen by the server).

So, when you call `room.createRtpStreamer()` you provide a `Producer`, and the generated `RtpStreamer` [2] has an associated `Consumer` and `PlainRtpTransport`. So, you should read the `rtpStreamer.consumer.rtpParameters` rather than the `producer`'s ones.

- [1] https://mediasoup.org/documentation/mediasoup/api/#server-Room
- [2] https://mediasoup.org/documentation/mediasoup/api/#RtpStreamer

Comment: When I call createRtpStreamer it's too late in the process since it will start to send the RTP packets. What I need is in the DESCRIBE stage, so I want to call the createRtpStreamer only when I get PLAY, unless there is a way to create a streamer at a stoped state and start it afterwards

Comment: Once you create the `RtpStreamer` you can pause its associated `Consumer` instance via `rtpStreamer.consumer.pause()` and then call `resume()` on it later.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the SDP of the call setup message and check whether you get 111 or 100 for the OPUS payload.
From there you can decide which part has the bug (Chrome or mediasoup).
In the call setup message (initiating the call) check the payload of the OPUS code.
The called party should respond with the same payload number if it accepts OPUS and then both parties should use the same payload number in the RTP packets.

Answer (score 1):

So I found that the payload I get on `producer.rtpParameters.codecs[i].payloadType` was the original payload and that `room.createRtpStreamer` changes the payload type.

Ended up doing the below to resolve the issue

```
// get the payload (type) from the room.rtpCapabilities.codecs.preferredPayloadType for the specific codec
let payload = this.room.rtpCapabilities.codecs.find((c)=>{
    return c.name === producer.rtpParameters.codecs[i].name;
}).preferredPayloadType;
```